# Bash Wildcard use

Tags: bash

I am trying to remove files in a directory using `rm` and without deleting the directory itself in a script. The examples I see only do this while in the directory itself, and I would like to do it without navigating there.

I tried

```
rm "$(dirname $1)/filetokeep/*"
```

but it is not working. Any help?

Comment: a .sln file is passed in with the same name as its directory

Answer (score 6):

Quoting the wildcard inhibits expansion.

```
rm -- "$(dirname -- "$1")/filetokeep"/*
```

Using `--` ensures that values can't be interpreted as optional arguments rather than positional ones (so that things still work if the directory named in `$1` starts with a `-`).

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to bash. I was trying a bunch of stuff, looks like I'm over-using quotes. Removing the quotes on my original attempt also works.

Comment: @user2805565 Removing the quotes outright will cause bugs; you only want to take them off the last character.

Comment: ...actually, it should be `rm "$(dirname "$1")/filetokeep"/*` to be fully correct (inner quotes around the `$1` -- `$()` creates a new quoting context, so this really does work as given).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Better yet, `rm -- "$(dirname -- "$1")/filetokeep"/*`, in case `$1` ever starts with a hyphen.

Comment: @ruakh, I'm going to hope I don't step on anybody's toes by editing your proposal into the answer.

Comment: How about `f="${1%%/}"; rm -- "${f%/*}/filetokeep"/*` to avoid the dirname subshell?

Comment: @kojiro: That only works when `$1` contains `/`. When it doesn't, `$(dirname -- "$1")` would be `.`, whereas `${f%/*}` would be the same as `$1`. (I'm sure this is fixable -- `dirname` doesn't do anything that can't be reproduced in pure Bash -- but I'm not sure it's worth it.)

Comment: @ruakh yeah, good point, I suppose. It also gets weird if $1='/'.